Address Bar Not Hiding on Scroll in Mobile Browsers in Next.js 14 Production Build with TailwindCSS
I am working on a project using Next.js 14.2.17 with TailwindCSS. I've noticed that on the production build, the address bar of mobile browsers does not hide as I scroll down the page. However, this issue does not occur in the development build.
Interestingly, I didn't encounter this issue in another project where I used SCSS with Next.js 14.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Could this be related to TailwindCSS configuration or optimization in the production build? Any suggestions on what might cause this and how to fix it?
What I Tried:

Verified the issue occurs only in the production build and not in development.
Checked for TailwindCSS configurations that might affect the html, body, or overflow styles.
Tested different viewport and scroll-related styles, but the issue persists.

What I Expected:
The address bar should hide on scroll in mobile browsers, similar to how it behaves in development and other projects.
Here's my root layout.tsx
import "./globals.css";

import type { Metadata, Viewport } from "next";
import { sansFont, monoFont } from "@/lib/fonts";
import SessionProviderWrapper from "@/hooks/sessionProvider";
import Navbar from "@/components/navbar/Navbar";
import Footer from "@/components/footer/Footer";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: {
        default: "Grace",
        template: "%s | Grace",
    },
    description: "Home page of the Website",
    icons: {
        icon: "favicon.ico",
    },
    creator: "RushO",
};

export const viewport: Viewport = {
    themeColor: "#952AD3",
    width: "device-width",
    initialScale: 1,
    maximumScale: 1,
    userScalable: false,
};

const RootLayout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={`${sansFont.variable} ${monoFont.variable} antialiased`}>
                <SessionProviderWrapper>
                    <Navbar />
                    <main className="mx-5 my-5 min-h-screen">{children}</main>
                    <Footer />
                </SessionProviderWrapper>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
};

export default RootLayout;


